# jQuery datepicker hide dates in between two months

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any way to hide the dates in between the two months when the option of  `numberOfMonths: 2`.

I meant the first month's previous days and second month's next days to be enable and the days in between the two months will be hide.

**Expected output will be looks like below:**

*The red colored part to be hide*

[image: Red colored part to be hide]

**Update:** *Those [Feb 23-28 and May 1-10] need to be grayed out only.*

*I want to hide the [Apr 1-5] in the March and [Mar 30-31] in the April.*

[`Sample JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/arul4/obxmLhpo/1/)

Comment: What about the dates grayed out at the beginning of March (Feb 23-28) and end of April (May 1-10)?

Comment: @j08691: Those [Feb 23-28 and May 1-10] need to grayed out only. I want to hide the [Apr 1-5] in the March and [Mar 30-31] in the April

Comment: From what I remember, aren't those dates that are colored red selectable? So if they are in March, they should be able to click on April 2, and it should provide that date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one was giving me a hard time but I think you can do it with some CSS:

```
div.ui-datepicker-group-first td:not(.ui-datepicker-other-month) ~ td.ui-datepicker-other-month {
    visibility:hidden;
}
div.ui-datepicker-group-last td {
    visibility:hidden;
}
div.ui-datepicker-group-last td.ui-datepicker-other-month ~ td:not(.ui-datepicker-other-month), div.ui-datepicker-group-last td:not(.ui-datepicker-other-month), div.ui-datepicker-group-last td:not(.ui-datepicker-other-month) ~ td.ui-datepicker-other-month {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/obxmLhpo/2/)**

Comment: Just somewhat? Seems to do exactly what you asked.